# How to check if MAAS-DHCP service/daemon is running?

Tags: 14.04, maas, dhcp

We've configured MAAS to handle DHCP on our network. It was working fine for a while but suddenly MAAS refuses to respond to DHCP requests. How to debug this? Are there any logs I can check or is there any particular service or daemon that might have stopped?

**EDIT**: Upon some more googling I found that the service name is `maas-dhcp-server`. I checked its status. It was in `stopped/waiting` status. I restarted using `service maas-dhcp-server start`, it successfully started showing me a PID of the newly launched process. But this process seems to die immediately. I cant find it in the `ps` output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. On the web UI, MAAS was wrongly configured to manage DHCP on `eth0` instead of `eth1` where the actual private network existed. I reconfigured MAAS to manage the correct ethernet interface and now I can `restart` the `maas-dhcp-server` service and the `dhcpd` is up and running

Comment: BTW, a nice tool I found is dhcping.  It provides the packet an also dissects the fields for you.